# Ruby on rails, How to compare two hashesh value to each other's?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-2.3, ruby-3

I am trying compare one hash values to another hash values of perticular each key's.
like below as

```
db_data = [{"user_id"=>"000879", "dept"=>"1066", "type"=>"A", "rate"=>"999"},
          {"user_id"=>"000879", "dept"=>"1066","type"=>"AB", "rate"=>"999"},
          {"user_id"=>"008118", "dept"=>"10000869", "type"=>"A", "rate"=>"950"}]

file_data = [{"user"=>"00094967",  "dept_id"=>"0020",  "price"=>950, "div_type"=>"A"},
            {"user"=>"00094967", "dept_id"=>"0020",  "price"=>950, "div_type"=>"A"},
            {"user"=>"00094967",  "dept_id"=>"0020", "price"=>950, "div_type"=>"AB"}]
```

I need to compare specific key of value from first hash data to compare with second hash specific key of value to each.
like  from file_data `dept_id` compare to db_data all keys `dept` value and if not getting then store in varaible(different data store)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
results = []
existed = false
file_data.each do |fd|
  dept_id = fd['dept_id']
  db_data.each do |dd|
    if dept_id == dd['dept']
      existed = true
      break
    end
  end
  results << fd if existed == false

  existed = false
end

# {"user"=>"00094967", "dept_id"=>"0020", "price"=>950, "div_type"=>"A"}
# {"user"=>"00094967", "dept_id"=>"0020", "price"=>950, "div_type"=>"A"}
# {"user"=>"00094967", "dept_id"=>"0020", "price"=>950, "div_type"=>"AB"}
# because dept_id 0020 is not existed in db_data, so it will go to result
```

so if dept_id is existed in the first loop on db_data it will not store the data to result. if until last element of db_data is not existed then it will go to result. then the flag existed will reset to false again.

Maybe that is not rubyist way, but it will do

Comment: It's working well, I changing little bit in it.

Answer (score 0):

If I got the point, you could just use [Array#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-select):

```
file_data.select { |h| !db_data.map { |hh| hh['dept'] }.include? h['dept_id'] }
```

Where `db_data.map { |hh| hh['dept'] }` is an array containing the values at key `'dept'`.

Comment: `map` is a bit overkill (create a new `Array` just to dispose of it) instead we can go with `file_data.select { |h| db.none? {|hh| hh['dept'] == h['dept_id']}}`